# protractor instance does not do anything

Tags: angularjs, protractor

from one to anothet day i cannot interact with the angular page i am testing.

The only result i get:

```
Started
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
F
```

the page has this:

```
<html lang="sv" class="no-js" data-ng-app="app">
```

So it should work, or not?
I tried checking on iFrames and also enhanced the allScriptTimeout: 360000, but nothing helped.

here is my config:

```
var TIMEOUT = 360000;
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
    dest: 'report/screenshots',
    filename: 'my-report.html'
});
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://dmc-l01-ap08.dmc.de:4448/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: 'https://int.system.com/',

    specs: [
        './UseCases/protractorTestcaseNightly.js',
    ],

    Capabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            shardTestFiles: false,
            maxInstances: 1,
            maxSessions: -1,
            restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
        },
    ],

    getPageTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    allScriptsTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: TIMEOUT,
        includeStackTrace : true,
        isVerbose : true,
    },
    framework: "jasmine2",
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

        var reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        var junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            savePath: 'report/xml',
            consolidateAll: false,
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    }
};
```

UPDATE:
I added

```
rootElement: 'html',
```

to my config. But nothing changed. I also took a screenshot from the page before clicking the first element. In the screenshot i can see the element i want to click at.

this is my Testspec:

```
describe('Start testspec | ', function () {

    it('opens the start', function () {
        browser.get("/de-de/connect/").then(function () {
            console.log("1"); //works
            browser.executeScript('localStorage.clear();sessionStorage.clear();'); //works (?)
            console.log("2"); //works
            expect(element(by.xpath('//*[@class="btn-link"]'))).toBeTruthy(); //works
            console.log("3"); //works


            browser.sleep(3000);  //works
            element(by.css('.ms-linklist-typ-1 a')).click(); //DOES NOT WORK :(
            browser.sleep(3000); //works
        });
    });
});
```

I do have to click on the "btn-link" / css element, because this is the cookie layer, which has to be clicked first before i can reach any other element...
any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with the test spec also .. a code snippet of the `it` block where you are seeing this issue .. may that will help to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i found the fix. My tests are running again by changing the versions of my installation. I looks like there is incompatibility between some version. It now works with:

```
Node LTS (6.10.0)
Selenium Server Standalone 3.0.1
protractor@5.1.1
npm@4.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the timeout configuration incorrectly. `allScriptTimeout` is only for the backend application scripts is not for the overall Jasmine spec

Please take a look at the three timeouts explained below

- [allScriptsTimeout](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L362) - This timeout config indicates the time
  application needs to finish running back-end scripts
- [getPageTimeout](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L367) - This indicates the time to wait for Page
  Load
- [jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L524) - This indicates the
  time    that Jasmine waits for overall spec

So in your case you increase the `jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval` to increase the timeout for overall spec

Try making the below change and see if this resolves the issue

```
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
        includeStackTrace : true,
        isVerbose : true,
    },
```

Also, Protractor assumes your angular-app root element to be `body`. Please see the below extract from the documentation below. Since your `ng-app` resides on a different element , may be update the `config.js` accordingly

> /**    * CSS Selector for the element housing the angular app - this
>   defaults to    * 'body', but is necessary if ng-app is on a descendant
>   of .    */

```
 rootElement?: string;
```